# Get list of in-app purchases (order ids) in iTunes Connect reports

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

My first app with in-app purchases just released on the app store. The buyer gets an email as purchase receipt with an order ID in it.
But I can't find the order ID - or any list with each single sale - on the iTunes Connect site.

I had a look into the user guide but there is no order Id in their.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to make check if a person claims he/she has bought the in-app feature? Something else than the order id maybe?

I do have a list of order ids for the android version of the app in the Google Wallet Merchant Account. Hopefully Apple has something similar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you find the answer?

Comment: To my knowledge this is not possible. I have searched for this question quet a bit.

Comment: Nope sorry. Nothing yet :(